# Randomizing without duplicating multiple times

Tags: javascript, string, random

I have the following task to perform. I get a string which I must write in reverse and also randomize the words in order to form 5 different strings. I have mananged to write the string in reverse and randomize the words, but I'm not able to do it 5 times. Here is the code.

```
var x = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
var wordsArray = x.split(" ");


function wordsReverse(allWords){
    var otherArray = [];
    for ( var i = allWords.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        otherArray.push(allWords[i]);
    }
    return otherArray;
}

function createRandomText(text){
    var randomArray = [];
    var randomText = null;
    for ( var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        for ( var k = 0; k < text.length; k++) {
            randomText = text[Math.floor(Math.random()*text.length)];
            if ( text[randomText] === undefined ) {
                randomArray.push(randomText);
                text[randomText] = true;
            }

        }   
    }

    return randomArray;
}

console.log(wordsReverse(wordsArray).toString().replace(/\,/g, ' '))
console.log(createRandomText(wordsArray).toString().replace(/\,/g, ' '))
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Why are you doing -> `.toString().replace(/\,/g, ' '))`  instead of `.join('')`  ?, Also your deleting elements out of the array each time, so there is nothing left. So you might want to clone the array first, and work off that.  Or create an Object literal to store what you've used.

Answer (score 0):

Loop it until you get all 5 random string. If string is not in array loop back.

```
var randomArray = [];

While(randomArray.length != 5){
   wordsReverse(wordsArray).toString().replace(/\,/g, ' ');
   var str = createRandomText(wordsArray).toString().replace(/\,/g, ' ');
   if(randomArray.indexOf(str) < -1) {
     randomArray.push(str);
   }
}
```